# Android: how apply transparency mask to a Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a ARGB_8888 Bitmap, which I need to apply an alpha mask to prior to painting to the canvas.  The Alpha mask is a stream of bytes representing the alpha channel for the image.  I could retrieve the int array of pixel values for the Bitmap, loop through the array and set the alpha for each pixel, create a bitmap from the new pixel values, and paint it to the canvas; but this seems extremely inefficient.  So, I was hoping to use some built in functionality for apply masks to bitmaps; but can't find anything useful.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, make sure you have a mutable Bitmap with `Bitmap.isMutable()`.

Have you tried `Bitmap.setHasAlpha` and using arithmetic operations on your mutable `Bitmap` to simply "add" the alpha channel?

That is, if you have a pixel that is `#00FF0000`, you can add `#FF000000` to make it completely transparent.

This would be much more efficient than copying to a new `Bitmap`.

Maybe something like

```
int desiredAlpha = 0x0F000000;
for(int i = 0; i < Bitmap.getwidth; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < Bitmap.getHeight; j++)
    {
         Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.getPixel(i,j) + desiredAlpha);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you want a .getHeight() in one loop ;)

Comment: Silly me! :D  Thanks for the sharp eye!

Comment: Thanks; but this is still far slower than I would like.  I was really hoping for some sort of blend mode or AlphaMaskFilter or something similar

Comment: if you're looking for something more complex/faster, I recommend you ditch the canvas and go for OpenGL operations.